# How to get the maximum memory available for contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-backup-service

i'm making a simple backup app and i'll be backing up contacts with it please is it possible to get the maximum number of memory available to contacts in the phone memory so i can use it to set a progress bar which says for example 74/100 (74 contacts used out of 100 contacts) because some older phones i've seen have this feature...is that possible in android or the contact memory is unlimited as long as phone internal storage is available?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2011 Google's contacts backend had a systemic limit of 10,000 contacts and 128KB maximum data per-contact.  I know of no public change of this limit.  Given that android contacts are synced with gmail contacts this would be one limit of interest.  Of course I believe you can store contacts on the device itself without synchronizing to gmail, and therefore the limit is likely whatever the row limits are in the underlying SQLITE database.  That number seems to vary around 2GB and 1TB depending upon when someone checks and what API or method they are using to determine that value.